# ServiceStack auth cookies different clients

Tags: servicestack

I encouraged my company to use ServiceStack for one of the software projects. I am loving servicestack framework by all means. I came accross a problem that I couldn't figure out by myself.
In a web application i am using ServiceStack c# Jsonclient from a login page to authenticate. When i get authenticated c# client hold the ss-id cookies in it. So when i use same c# client for service calls i can access the session within my services.
But there is a autocomplete feature which calls a service by Jquery AJAX call the client there (browser) is not authenticated and browser does not hold ss-id cookie also. 
My question is when i authenticate with c# client on code-behind. How can i store session cookies on browser (Is that needed?) so when i call service from javascript client i can access session in my services also.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My question is when i authenticate with c# client on code-behind. How can i store session cookies on browser (Is that needed?)**

So, your browser needs to have a session cookie to let ServiceStack know that it has been successfully authenticated. The browser knows nothing about what is happening with your C# clients. I'm not sure how you are posting your authentication data (username/password/etc) but if it is through a browser and you're handing the data off to a C# client you could do something like below. This is wihin MVC but the point is to get the session cookie out of the client and into the response to the browser.

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost");

        var response = client.Post(new Auth() {UserName = "TestUser", Password = "Password"} );

        var ssId = "";
        foreach(Cookie c in client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost")))
        {
            if (c.Name == "ss-id")
            {
                ssId = c.Value;
            }
        }


        var cookie = new HttpCookie("ss-id", ssId);
        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

If you are using MVC [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L48) would be a better way. However, I'm not sure your reasoning for using C# clients and how your are receiving the authentication data and your ability to get into the Response to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the projects. I will use as shown in ServiceStack.Usecase CustomAuthentication project.

Answer (score 0):

Setting both "ss-id" and "ss-pid" cookies works for me when authenticating the browser as well as the .NET client.
A somewhat rewritten part of my logon controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logon(Auth auth)
{
    using (var client = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient("://ServicestackUrl/"))
    {
        auth.provider = "credentials";
        auth.RememberMe = true;
        client.UserName = auth.UserName;
        client.Password = auth.Password;
        var authResponse = new AuthResponse();
        try
        {
            authResponse = client.Send(auth);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        foreach (Cookie c in client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(client.BaseUri)))
        {
            if (c.Name == "ss-id" || c.Name == "ss-pid")
            {
                Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("ss-id", c.Value));
            }
        }

        //Log the user on with forms authentication
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(
                new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1,
                authResponse.UserName,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes),
                false,
                ""
            )
        );
        Response.Cookies.Add(
            new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
        );
    }

    //Do a redirect or something
    return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl);
}
```